# REST API only sets certain properties of object

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, rest, datacontract

I am working on a REST API that I post to using POST and XML as the content.  In my WebInvoke method, it seems to only be serializing a few of the properties. For example, I pass FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, and Address, but it isn't setting the Email and Address properties.  So when it adds the data to my database, those fields are blank.

Why is this?  Why is it setting some of the properties but not others?  I've tried re-arranging the order and that didn't affect anything.  That also brings me to one other question: Do ALL the properties have to be passed in the xml, or will only passing a few like I have here suffice?  I hope the answer is it doesn't need all, because this may be a pretty dynamic system and new properties may be added frequently without the xml being changed.

Here is some of the relevant code:

```cs
public class Lead
{
    #region Public Properties
    [DataMember(Name = "LeadId")]
    public int LeadId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "MiddleName")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Email2")]
    public string Email2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Phone2")]
    public string Phone2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Address2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Address3")]
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "State")]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Zip")] etc...
```

Here's the OperationContract

```cs
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "leads",
        BodyStyle= WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string AddLead(Lead lead);
```

Here's the AddLead function in the Service:

```cs
public string AddLead(Lead lead)
    {
        string result = lead.Submit();
        if (result == "Success")
        {
            return "Success. " + lead.LeadId;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And here is the XML that I'm passing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Lead xmlns="http://www.myrenamednamespace.com/leads">
      <FirstName>John</FirstName>
      <LastName>Doe</LastName>
      <Email>JohnDoe@gmail.com</Email>
      <Phone>8885551234</Phone>
      <Address>123 Fake St</Address>
      <City>Fake City</City>
   </Lead>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the order on the DataMember. The DataContractSerializer assumes alphabetic ordering unless you tell it otherwise and it ignores items it finds out of the expected order (which is why it did phone but not email successfully)

```
public class Lead
{
    [DataMember(Name = "LeadId", Order=1)]
    public int LeadId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "FirstName", Order = 2)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "MiddleName", Order = 3)]
     public string MiddleName { get; set; }

     // ... etc
}
```